# Efficient way to format string using dict keys, without reusing the intermittent variable

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have the following that I would like to write more efficiently, i.e. without repeating unnecessary code:

```
print('{}, {}'.format(my_list.json()['profile']['name'], my_list.json()['profile']['age']))
```

Is there a way to write what I am doing without having to repeat `my_list.json()['profile']` so many times? Or even just without having to write the `['profile']` prefix each time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can unpack `**` your dictionary via using named keys during string formatting as:

```
print('{name}, {age}'.format(**my_list.json()['profile']))
```

Comment: Thank you, this is really cool. Is there a way to get this to work when you don't want to *unpack* all the elements, only some?